# Timeline JavaScript plug-in with Call Graph

Tags: jquery-plugins, graphics, d3.js, javascript

I need to build something similar to this UI http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-b0r71ZbJdmA/T9DYhbE0uXI/AAAAAAAAABs/bXwyM76Iddc/s1600/web-screenshot.png.

The time scale has to be in milliseconds.  Basically, I need a component similar to Chrome -> Timeline -> Event Window -> Records ,  which shows call graph with time spend in ms in each node.

If you know of any, please let me know it would be great help.  Once again thanks for help.

[image: Image That shows Call Graph and Time Spent in ms]

Thanks,
Bhavesh

Comment: That's [twitter zipkin](http://twitter.github.io/zipkin/)

Comment: I know but it here JavaScript Lib that provide this functionality.

Comment: It's built on top of [D3](http://d3js.org/). here's one example: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~bederson/papers/index.html generally you can use div with given width to do simplest horizontal timeline.